# How to do validation for multiple images upload in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, validation, frameworks, laravel-5.3

I've an input

```
    <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

and controller function

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    foreach ($request->image as $image)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);
        $imageName = mt_rand() .time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
                                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    })->save(public_path('images/thumbs').'/'.$imageName);
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
    }
}
```

but all the time validator gives me error that

```
    The image must be an image.
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Move validation outside the loop and try with the rules:

```
 'image' => 'required',
 'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
```

Comment: this is best answer

Comment: It worked, but can you explain a bit deeply, why it should be outside?

Comment: The first directive, "image", is for the field. The second directive, "image.*", is for the files themselves. In your loop, you were essentially validating the field over and over.

Comment: @misdreavus79 that was an explanation I would like to have found in all the other threads out there. Thanks for pointing that out, about the 'image' and 'image.*'

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($images as $img) {
    $request->validate([
       'multi_img.*' => ['required', 'image', 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg', 'max:2048'],
     ]);}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.