# Laravel File validation rule "Required" not working

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

So the title says all, other rules like "mimes" are works, but I can submit form without file upload. Ofcourse I can use "required" attr in HTML, but I don't want to.

`Controller`

```
$rules = [
    'img.*' => 'required|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg',
    ];

$customMessages = [
    'img.required' => 'Yo, what should I call you?',
    ];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

`View`

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('img.'.$i) ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

    <label for="img">File input</label>
    <input  type="file" class="form-control-file" id="img" value="{{old('img.'.$i)}}" name="img[]">
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('img.'.$i) }}</small>

</div>
```

I have other inputs, but with `type="text"` and their `"required"` rule works fine. Whats wrong with `type="file"`? Can't find the answer...

Comment: What version of laravel is this?

Comment: It's Laravel  5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in `$iter` in my div for input `type="file"` It should look like this:

```
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('img') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label for="img">File input</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="img" value="{{old('img')}}" name="img[]">
      <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('img') }}</small>
 </div>
```

But, after I delete my variable mimes stopped work:)

```
$rules = [
        'img' => 'required',
        'img.*' => 'image|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg'
    ];
```

or

```
$rules = [
        'img.*' => 'required|image|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg'
    ];
```

Answer (score 2):

In your opening form tag you have add this:

enctype="multipart/form-data"

and remove name="img[]"
use name ="img"

Comment: Nope, my enctype is ok. And I can't remove array because my input are dynamic, so I'll store a lot of images to DB. Other inputs with [] are works ok

Comment: 'img.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg'

Comment: nothing, rules for mimes and image are works, but I still can submit a form with an empty file input

Comment: var_dump($errors->get('img.0')); and the result is : array(0) { }

Comment: so this means you are not getting image, can you show the code of request , means how you getting image through request

Comment: Yea, thats right, my input are empty and I can submit the form with an empty input. Thats wrong. And what do u mean code of request. Didn't understand u a bit, probably cause of  my lack of eng skills

Comment: something like this   $img = count($this->input('img'));

Comment: may be this is helpful http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/

Comment: Input are not working in Laravel 5.5 btw. 
Thanks for link, but it won't help, cause his type="file" field are not required in rules..
Thats the only rule that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
<input  type="file" class="form-control-file" id="img" value="{{old('img.'.$i)}}" name="img[]" multiple>


$rules = [
        'img' => 'required',
        'img.*' => 'image|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg'
    ];
```

Comment: @qqmydarling : Please follow this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727463/how-to-do-validation-for-multiple-images-upload-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: I was watching a lot of links and didn't find an answer, there is no solution for me. Btw, I don't need a multiple attr cause I have a lot of inputs with the same "name" attr and files will be saved by one submit. My form looks like:
Name - Description - File

Answer (score 0):

`Controller`

```
$rules = [
    'img' => 'required',
    'img.*' => 'image|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg',
];

$customMessages = [
    'img.required' => 'Yo, what should I call you?',
];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

`form`

```
<form action="...." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
.
.
.
.

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('img.'.$i) ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

        <label for="img">File input</label>
        <input  type="file" class="form-control-file" id="img" value="{{old('img.'.$i)}}" name="img[]">
        <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('img.'.$i) }}</small>

    </div>
```

Comment: How will it help,If I'll make validation outside the loop? 
Other inputs works ok, and required rule works ok on type="text"
And I can't move my file input outside the loop cause I have a js script that clone my inputs so they're dynamic