# how to validate mimes files laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm trying to validate the uploaded image to be only of this type `mimes: jpeg, jpg, png` but the problem is if I put the code like this:

```
'photos' => 'required|array|max:5|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
'photos.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
```

It validates as expected like this `The image must be a file of type:jpg,jpeg,png only`, but even if I upload the jpg or png file still shows `The image must be a file of type:jpg,jpeg,png only`. And if I put the code like this:

```
'photos' => 'required|array|max:5',
'photos.*' => 'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg',
```

It does not validate so I can even upload a video, psd, and other files which are not of this type `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png` . How can I validate the uploaded file to be only of this type `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png`?

Controller

```
$this->validate(
    $request, 
    [
    'photos' => 'required|array|max:5',
    'photos.*' => 'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do validation for multiple images upload in laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727463/how-to-do-validation-for-multiple-images-upload-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: I saw that question but it doesn't work in my case @RohitMittal

Answer (score 2):

this is correction from your code

```
'photos' => 'required|array|max:5'
'photos.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
```

and make sure you put enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form like this

```
<form action url enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

this made browser actually send file(s) to server (view to controller),

then mimes can recognize/catch the file extension you sent from browser

this might explain better from laravel documentation [Laravel validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-mimes)

Answer (score 2):

You can check below code:

```
'photos' => 'required|array|size:5',
'photos.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
```

`size` is used to limit the uploaded image count and `max` is used to limit the size of each uploading file. Hope it helps you!!